# Matlab: Extract LxN array from LxMxN array

Tags: arrays, matlab, multidimensional-array, resize, size

Suppose `x=zeros(L,M,N)`. For a fixed component, the remaining array is basically a matrix. So I should be able to do something like `y = x(:,2,:)`. Then, I expect `y` to be a matrix, i.e. an LxN array. But I instead get a Lx1xN array.

How can I obtain a standard matrix from a three-dimensional array, after I fixed one component? I use matlab.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`reshape`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html):

```
y = reshape(x(:,2,:), [L N]);
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [`permute`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/permute.html) to rearrange the dimensions after indexing:

```
x = zeros(2,3,4); % L×M×N
y = permute(x(:,2,:), [1 3 2]); % move 2nd dimension to 3rd
```

The code sends the second dimension to the end. This transforms the `L`×`1`×`N` array into an `L`×`N`×`1` array, which is the *same* as an `L`×`N` matrix, because trailing singleton dimensions [are ignored](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/95966-why-are-leading-singleton-dimensions-not-dropped-when-displaying-size-of-multidimensional-arrays); in fact, arrays can be considered to have an [infinite number](https://web.archive.org/web/20160801002244/https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/multidimensional-arrays.html) of trailing singleton dimensions. As a check,

```
>> size(y)
ans =
     2     4
```

---

A word of caution: some people may be tempted to use the simpler `y = squeeze(x(:,2,:))`, but that squeezes *all* (non-trailing) singleton dimensions, not just the second, and so it gives a *wrong* result for `L=1`.